# Definition for ROS packages on Debian Squeeze

Tags: ros, rosdep, ros-fuerte, dependencies, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody, I am trying to install ROS on Debian.
I followed the experimental guide for installing ROS Fuerte in Debian. Everything went well except when I have to launch the command:
rosdep install -ay

I receive the output shown below and it fails.
I saw that for gentoo someone solved this problem using a custom 20-default.list. Is there anything like that for Debian Squeeze 6.0.5 ?
Thank you.
John

```
john@debreef:~$ rosdep install -ay
Executing script below with cwd=/tmp
{{{
#!/bin/bash
export PREFIX=/usr/
[ f932cebad87302d8ea0ec1fd39b24d99 = `cat $PREFIX/include/eigen3/eigen-version.installed` ]

}}}

cat: /usr//include/eigen3/eigen-version.installed: No such file or directory
/tmp/tmpQxTN84: line 3: [: f932cebad87302d8ea0ec1fd39b24d99: unary operator expected
Executing script below with cwd=/tmp
{{{
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
dpkg-query -W -f='${Package} ${Status}\n' yaml-cpp-sourcedep 2>&1 | awk '{\
if ($4 =="installed") 
  exit 0
else
  print "yaml-cpp-sourcedep not installed"
  exit 1}'

}}}

yaml-cpp-sourcedep not installed
Executing script below with cwd=/tmp
{{{
#!/bin/bash
export PREFIX=/usr/
if [ -f $PREFIX/include/assimp/assimp-version.installed ]; then
  [ 2ed0b9954bcb2572c0dade8f849b9260 = `cat $PREFIX/include/assimp/assimp-version.installed` ]
else
  false
fi

}}}

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
image_view: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
runtime_monitor: No definition of [swig-wx] for OS [debian]
carrot_planner: Missing resource pcl
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/john/ros/navigation
ROS path [2]=/home/john/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [3]=/home/john/ros/common
ROS path [4]=/home/john/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [5]=/home/john/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [6]=/home/john/ros/simulator_gazebo
ROS path [7]=/home/john/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [8]=/home/john/ros/geometry
ROS path [9]=/home/john/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [10]=/home/john/ros/bullet
ROS path [11]=/home/john/ros/robot_model
ROS path [12]=/home/john/ros/xacro
ROS path [13]=/home/john/ros/image_transport_plugins
ROS path [14]=/home/john/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [15]=/home/john/ros/stage
ROS path [16]=/home/john/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [17]=/home/john/ros/driver_common
ROS path [18]=/home/john/ros/physics_ode
ROS path [19]=/home/john/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [20]=/home/john/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [21]=/home/john/ros/bond_core
ROS path [22]=/home/john/ros/image_common
ROS path [23]=/home/john/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [24]=/home/john/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [25]=/home/john/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [26]=/home/john/ros/bfl
ROS path [27]=/home/john/ros/image_pipeline
ROS path [28]=/home/john/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [29]=/home/john/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [30]=/home/john/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [31]=/home/john/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [32]=/home/john/ros/vision_opencv
ROS path [33]=/home/john/ros/visualization
ROS path [34]=/home/john/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [35]=/home/john/ros/slam_gmapping
ROS path [36]=/home/john/ros/filters
ROS path [37]=/home/john/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [38]=/home/john/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [39]=/home/john/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [40]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [41]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [42]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
image_rotate: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
rotate_recovery: Missing resource pcl
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/john/ros/navigation
ROS path [2]=/home/john/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [3]=/home/john/ros/common
ROS path [4]=/home/john/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [5]=/home/john/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [6]=/home/john/ros/simulator_gazebo
ROS path [7]=/home/john/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [8]=/home/john/ros/geometry
ROS path [9]=/home/john/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [10]=/home/john/ros/bullet
ROS path [11]=/home/john/ros/robot_model
ROS path [12]=/home/john/ros/xacro
ROS path [13]=/home/john/ros/image_transport_plugins
ROS path [14]=/home/john/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [15]=/home/john/ros/stage
ROS path [16]=/home/john/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [17]=/home/john/ros/driver_common
ROS path [18]=/home/john/ros/physics_ode
ROS path [19]=/home/john/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [20]=/home/john/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [21]=/home/john/ros/bond_core
ROS path [22]=/home/john/ros/image_common
ROS path [23]=/home/john/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [24]=/home/john/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [25]=/home/john/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [26]=/home/john/ros/bfl
ROS path [27]=/home/john/ros/image_pipeline
ROS path [28]=/home/john/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [29]=/home/john/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [30]=/home/john/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [31]=/home/john/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [32]=/home/john/ros/vision_opencv
ROS path [33]=/home/john/ros/visualization
ROS path [34]=/home/john/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [35]=/home/john/ros/slam_gmapping
ROS path [36]=/home/john/ros/filters
ROS path [37]=/home/john/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [38]=/home/john/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [39]=/home/john/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [40]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [41]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [42]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
opencv_tests: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
depth_image_proc: Missing resource pcl
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/john/ros/navigation
ROS path [2]=/home/john/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [3]=/home/john/ros/common
ROS path [4]=/home/john/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [5]=/home/john/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [6]=/home/john/ros/simulator_gazebo
ROS path [7]=/home/john/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [8]=/home/john/ros/geometry
ROS path [9]=/home/john/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [10]=/home/john/ros/bullet
ROS path [11]=/home/john/ros/robot_model
ROS path [12]=/home/john/ros/xacro
ROS path [13]=/home/john/ros/image_transport_plugins
ROS path [14]=/home/john/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [15]=/home/john/ros/stage
ROS path [16]=/home/john/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [17]=/home/john/ros/driver_common
ROS path [18]=/home/john/ros/physics_ode
ROS path [19]=/home/john/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [20]=/home/john/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [21]=/home/john/ros/bond_core
ROS path [22]=/home/john/ros/image_common
ROS path [23]=/home/john/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [24]=/home/john/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [25]=/home/john/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [26]=/home/john/ros/bfl
ROS path [27]=/home/john/ros/image_pipeline
ROS path [28]=/home/john/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [29]=/home/john/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [30]=/home/john/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [31]=/home/john/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [32]=/home/john/ros/vision_opencv
ROS path [33]=/home/john/ros/visualization
ROS path [34]=/home/john/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [35]=/home/john/ros/slam_gmapping
ROS path [36]=/home/john/ros/filters
ROS path [37]=/home/john/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [38]=/home/john/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [39]=/home/john/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [40]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [41]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [42]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
pcl_ros: No definition of [pcl] for OS [debian]
python_qt_binding: No definition of [ros] for OS [debian]
navfn: No definition of [pcl] for OS [debian]
image_proc: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
rviz: No definition of [python-qt-bindings] for OS [debian]
gazebo_worlds: Missing resource protobuf
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/john/ros/navigation
ROS path [2]=/home/john/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [3]=/home/john/ros/common
ROS path [4]=/home/john/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [5]=/home/john/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [6]=/home/john/ros/simulator_gazebo
ROS path [7]=/home/john/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [8]=/home/john/ros/geometry
ROS path [9]=/home/john/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [10]=/home/john/ros/bullet
ROS path [11]=/home/john/ros/robot_model
ROS path [12]=/home/john/ros/xacro
ROS path [13]=/home/john/ros/image_transport_plugins
ROS path [14]=/home/john/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [15]=/home/john/ros/stage
ROS path [16]=/home/john/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [17]=/home/john/ros/driver_common
ROS path [18]=/home/john/ros/physics_ode
ROS path [19]=/home/john/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [20]=/home/john/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [21]=/home/john/ros/bond_core
ROS path [22]=/home/john/ros/image_common
ROS path [23]=/home/john/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [24]=/home/john/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [25]=/home/john/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [26]=/home/john/ros/bfl
ROS path [27]=/home/john/ros/image_pipeline
ROS path [28]=/home/john/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [29]=/home/john/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [30]=/home/john/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [31]=/home/john/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [32]=/home/john/ros/vision_opencv
ROS path [33]=/home/john/ros/visualization
ROS path [34]=/home/john/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [35]=/home/john/ros/slam_gmapping
ROS path [36]=/home/john/ros/filters
ROS path [37]=/home/john/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [38]=/home/john/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [39]=/home/john/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [40]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [41]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [42]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
cv_bridge: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
tf2_visualization: No definition of [swig-wx] for OS [debian]
rxbag_plugins: No definition of [swig-wx] for OS [debian]
librviz_tutorial: No definition of [python-qt-bindings] for OS [debian]
gazebo: No definition of [tbb] for OS [debian]
camera_calibration: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
image_geometry: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
move_base: No definition of [pcl] for OS [debian]
gazebo_tests: No definition of [tbb] for OS [debian]
compressed_image_transport: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
robot_monitor: No definition of [swig-wx] for OS [debian]
opencv2: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
laser_filters: No definition of [pcl] for OS [debian]
gazebo_tools: No definition of [tbb] for OS [debian]
gazebo_plugins: Missing resource pcl
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/john/ros/navigation
ROS path [2]=/home/john/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [3]=/home/john/ros/common
ROS path [4]=/home/john/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [5]=/home/john/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [6]=/home/john/ros/simulator_gazebo
ROS path [7]=/home/john/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [8]=/home/john/ros/geometry
ROS path [9]=/home/john/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [10]=/home/john/ros/bullet
ROS path [11]=/home/john/ros/robot_model
ROS path [12]=/home/john/ros/xacro
ROS path [13]=/home/john/ros/image_transport_plugins
ROS path [14]=/home/john/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [15]=/home/john/ros/stage
ROS path [16]=/home/john/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [17]=/home/john/ros/driver_common
ROS path [18]=/home/john/ros/physics_ode
ROS path [19]=/home/john/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [20]=/home/john/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [21]=/home/john/ros/bond_core
ROS path [22]=/home/john/ros/image_common
ROS path [23]=/home/john/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [24]=/home/john/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [25]=/home/john/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [26]=/home/john/ros/bfl
ROS path [27]=/home/john/ros/image_pipeline
ROS path [28]=/home/john/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [29]=/home/john/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [30]=/home/john/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [31]=/home/john/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [32]=/home/john/ros/vision_opencv
ROS path [33]=/home/john/ros/visualization
ROS path [34]=/home/john/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [35]=/home/john/ros/slam_gmapping
ROS path [36]=/home/john/ros/filters
ROS path [37]=/home/john/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [38]=/home/john/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [39]=/home/john/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [40]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [41]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [42]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
turtle_tf: No definition of [qt4-qmake] for OS [debian]
laser_assembler: No definition of [pcl] for OS [debian]
turtle_actionlib: No definition of [qt4-qmake] for OS [debian]
rxtools: No definition of [swig-wx] for OS [debian]
rviz_plugin_tutorials: No definition of [python-qt-bindings] for OS [debian]
theora_image_transport: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
rxbag: No definition of [swig-wx] for OS [debian]
stereo_image_proc: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
turtlesim: No definition of [qt4-qmake] for OS [debian]
cv_markers: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40131/definition-for-ros-packages-on-debian-squeeze/) by [kaharoth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2947/kaharoth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-07-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Overall I think your problem is that there's quite a few rosdep rules which are not filled in for debian.  [How to submit rosdep rules](http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/contributing_rules.html) You will also likely run into issues that there may be packages available for ubuntu but not debian which will need to be satisfied from source.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1